# Concatenating dataframes single label row selection returns multiple rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have three DataFrame objects with the same column names, with a column 'a' of interest to me that I would sort on eventually. And, once they are combined, I would like to access them iteratively.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df1['src'] = np.array(['str1' for i in range(len(df1))])
df2['src'] = np.array(['str2' for i in range(len(df2))])
df3['src'] = np.array(['str3' for i in range(len(df3))])

combo = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
combo.ix[0]

In [117]: combo.ix[0]
Out[117]: 
          a         b         c         d   src
0  1.002482 -1.801156 -0.413474 -0.714292  str1
0 -0.816205  0.670441  0.091646  1.290459  str2
0  0.543803  0.841918  0.281999  1.204264  str3

In [125]: df1.ix[0]
Out[125]: 
a      1.002482
b     -1.801156
c     -0.413474
d     -0.714292
src        str1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

In the above set, once concatenated, I no longer have the ability to get individual items. I am getting 3 for each indice. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass param `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)

```
In [2]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a','b','c','d'])

df1['src'] = np.array(['str1' for i in range(len(df1))])
df2['src'] = np.array(['str2' for i in range(len(df2))])
df3['src'] = np.array(['str3' for i in range(len(df3))])
combo = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True)
combo.ix[0]
Out[2]:
a      -0.839181
b     -0.1489309
c      -1.655775
d     -0.1682147
src         str1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```